# Why does my vue-svg-loader configuration not recognise SVG files?

Tags: vue.js, svg

I'm using vue-cli for my app and have added the appropriate config to my `config/index.js` file accordingly (per https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/#vue-cli):

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    // Omitted for brevity
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader');
  },
  dev: {
    // Ommitted for brevity
  }
}
```

vue-svg-loader was installed in my project using `npm install --save vue-svg-loader`.

My component is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg-logo />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import svgLogo from './logo.svg'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {svgLogo}
  }
</script>
```

The error I get on the server console when I try to load the page is as follows:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
|     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#314659" opacity=".5">
|         <rect width="19" height="11" x="2.5" y="6.5" rx="2"/>

 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue 98:0-74
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

Every SVG I try to load results in that same error.

Is there anything obvious that's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Are you configured `config/index.js` or `vue.config.js`?

Comment: Right you are, I had it in `config/index.js`. I've moved it to `vue.config.js` but it doesn't seem to make a difference. It doesn't look like `vue.config.js` is getting loaded though. I'm running the app using `npm run dev` and my package.json file defines that action as: `node build/dev-server.js`

Comment: What version of `vue` and `vue/cli` do you use? In the latest version, everything works.